# meaning of "command" prefix and suffix of "!"

Tags: vim

I am learning `vim` from `vimtutor` and I am currently on lesson 5 where they introduce external command prefix `!command` and external command suffix `command!`. I tested the command `ls` and did the following:

After typing `:!ls`, I got:

```
Desktop    Downloads  Music Public     TEST
Documents    Pictures   Templates  Videos

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

When I saw the lists of folders and files, I knew that it acted like typing `ls` in the terminal, but when I typed :ls!, it got:

```
:ls!
  1 %a   "/tmp/tutorhN8t15"             line 600
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Which made me confused of what the external command `!` really means. What does it really mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `:!command` executes external command `command`.
- `:command!` executes internal command `command` with a "bang" that usually modifies its behavior.

So…

- `:!ls` executes your shell's `ls` command, which lists the files and directories in the working directory.

  See `:help :!`.
- `:ls!` executes Vim's `ls` command in a way that forces it to show listed and unlisted buffers.

  See `:help :ls`.

Comment: After doing the `vimtutor`, I'll look for a resource to learn about commands on Linux since there are a lot of terms I am not familiar with. Thanks for citing out the differences.